# Why won't an XML array deserialize in a base object

Tags: .net, xml, deserialization

I have two classes, a documents and a document class. Both have attributes. When I attempt to deserialize the documents class I get the attribute and the element values but the array of documents is empty. If I deserialize the documents using the root as documents, then I get the proper array of documents but of course not the attribute or element from the documents. Is there some mojo I'm missing in the documents class so that it gets the array of documents?

```
    Public Class document

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("ID")>
    Public ID As Integer
    Public docType As String

End Class

Public Class documents

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("maxID")>
    Public maxID As Integer
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("document")>
    Public docs() As document
    Public docGroup As String

End Class


Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim _XML As String = "
<documents maxID=""12345"">
 <document ID=""33333"">
  <docType>Doc1</docType>
 </document>
 <document ID=""44444"">
  <docType>Doc2</docType>
 </document>
 <docGroup>Any</docGroup>
</documents>"

        Dim _ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim _sw As New StreamWriter(_ms)
        _sw.Write(_XML)
        _sw.Flush()
        _ms.Position = 0

        Dim _ser1 As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(documents))
        Dim _ser2 As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(document()), New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("documents"))

        Dim docs As documents
        Dim doc() As document
        Dim obj As Object

        _ms.Position = 0
        docs = _ser1.Deserialize(_ms)  '; Gets attribute and element but no document array
        _ms.Position = 0
        doc = _ser2.Deserialize(_ms)   ' Gets document array just fine
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: XML serialization default with arrays of creating two levels of tags 1) Element 2) Elements.  You xml string shows this with documents and document.  The attribute XmlArray is used for the parent documents.  The attribute XmlArrayItem is used for the child document.  You have this backwards.  You can force serialization to use only one tag by putting XmlElement as the attribute instead of XmlArray and XmlArrayItem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the tag to XmlElement as you suggested and it worked. Not sure I understand exactly why yet and what the condition would be to use the Array and ArrayItem in XML though. Could you provide a simple example XML of where Array and Array Item would be appropriate?

Comment: When the array is not the root of the xml.  If you had a parent Root in your xml just before the <documents> then documents would be the XmlArray and document would be the XmlArrayItem. in the root class.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your assistance.